# jQuery in a complex html view

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I am building an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC view, which has many and complex elements. For example content buttons (show more/ show less), buttons which filter visual elements by type and html calendar which filters the elements by period `<input type="date">`.

For all these actions to work, I use jQuery (v3.6.4). My question is, is there some kind of design patterns and best practices to manipulate that many elements.

For example, whenever I prompt the calendar filtering specific buttons are hidden, some elements get their values cleared etc. and this is done in a straightforward way (select the element and hide it, for example).

For example in many onclick functions, first I hide/show specific elements, using their selectors, then make some action. And sometimes it gets very repetitive, like boilerplate code.

So, if I can improve the repetitiveness and apply the KISS principle, would be great.

Comment: *General* practices include limiting DOM read/writes, using classes to group similar elements, using data-driven code to find related elements via data- attributes.

Comment: Oh yes, this seems very nice idea. I also understood that Observer pattern can be used. What do you think?